# Best way to merge multiple files without duplicating information

Tags: ruby, file, optimization

Given `N` different text files containing the scanning results of `N` antivirus, I would like to know the best, i.e. the most optimized, way to merge those files without the lines which are in common in different text files to be duplicated. So I came to 2 conclusions :

- Check for each line if it is already present in the final text file, and not write it if so
- Copy everything and remove duplicated lines

Maybe there are some other solutions, I don't know. Given this, what would be the best way to proceed ?

Comment: How large are the files -- small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: Use a `Hash` to keep track of whether you've seen a line before. In the hash, the keys will be the lines of data, and the values will be a boolean or (if you care) a count of how many times you saw each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the arrays and then `.uniq` on them perhaps?

```
1.9.3-p429 :001 > a = ['test', 'test2'] + ['test2', 'test3']
[
    [0] "test",
    [1] "test2",
    [2] "test2",
    [3] "test3"
]
1.9.3-p429 :002 > a.uniq
[
    [0] "test",
    [1] "test2",
    [2] "test3"
]
```

Of course, this would rely on the lines being exactly identical.